# Seemingly correct way to trigger Javascript function via link, not working

Tags: javascript, function, reset

Alright, so I've been reading and reading and ready about how to run some simple Javascript code when a link has been clicked, but no matter what I try, I can't seem to get it to work!

The idea is that when my link is clicked, it will change color and fill a variable, then when it is clicked again it is to change to another color and return the var back to the state it was (effectively resetting the first click)

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong here?

Here is my Javascript code:

```
window.onload = function() {

document.getElementById("atonal").onclick = function() {

    var categoryLink=new Array(); 
    var counter;
    categoryLink[0] = "empty";   
    categoryLink[1] = "empty";   
    categoryLink[3] = "empty";   
    counter = "0";

    if (categoryLink[0]=="empty") {
        categoryLink[0] = "atonal";
        counter = counter + 1;
        stylesheet.insertRule("#atonal {color: #FFFFFF}", 0);
    }

    if (categoryLink[0]=="atonal") {
        categoryLink[0] = "empty";
        counter = counter - 1;
        stylesheet.insertRule("#atonal {color: #474747}", 0);
    }

   return false;  
  }
}
```

And my HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="atonal">antonal sound</a>
```

Comment: When the link is clicked it's going to load `www.google.com`, there'll be no time to see your link changing colour.

Comment: Your second `if` should be an `else if`.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right. I had that in there as a test to see if the function was even being called.

Comment: Dont post untested code on SO.

Comment: Untested code? I'm confused. It has been tested, however it wasn't working so I posted it here to get assistance. Is that not the correct way of going about things here?

Comment: Can anyone tell me why this code won't work even after changing the syntax errors and removing the window.location? My best guess is that I'm not seeing the color change because this is not the way to alter CSS via Javascript?

Comment: There ought to be a rule that you can't post on SO until you've at least looked for syntax errors in your favorite error console!

Comment: While you're right that I should have checked for syntax errors, that still isn't the issue here. Something else is the problem. If anyone has any advice on what the issue is, it would be greatly appreciated. Repeatedly telling me there is a syntax error isn't helping anything.

Answer (score 1):

There are two identical syntax errors in this code; FireBug or equivalent would have showed these to you:

```
if (categoryLink[0}=="empty") {
```

That `}` ought to be a `]`, of course. Fix those, and your code will work -- or at least, your `onclick` will be registered and invoked when you expect.

Comment: Leave it to something small and simple to mess up a code! I've gone through 4-5 different methods that probably would have worked otherwise.

Thank you! I will check out this firebug too.

Comment: I fixed the syntax errors as you suggested, but alas, still no results. I'm guessing there is more wrong with my code than that!

Answer (score 1):

The comments about `window.location = "http://www.google.com/";` are correct.

But also, you have a syntax error in your last 2 `IF` statements:

```
if (categoryLink[0}=="empty") {
```

Should be:

```
if (categoryLink[0]=="empty") {
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ekxbu/